# SSRS Report - Sum up Value based on keyword

Tags: reporting-services

I have report that shows business unit and also count of cases under that business unit. However I need to sum up few business unit into one business unit. I can't do it on query level as the query are being shared with other report. You can refer to the picture below.

[image]

Kindly need your help on how can I filter it on report template level

Comment: Have you tried grouping data in a tablix by the business unit? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms170712.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to group all the "TMP xxx" business units together as a single BU.

Change the expression for the Business Unit field to be something like this.

```
=IIF(
LEFT(Fields!MyBUColumnName.Value,4) = "TMP "
, "TMP BU Group"
,Fields!MyBUColumnName.Value)
```

All we are doing here is using an expression that says "if the left 4 characters of the BU name are "TMP " then replace it with "TMP BU Group", if not then use the original BU name.

You must then also change the grouping in the report to use this same expression.